# Mouse movements go in wrong directions

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, mouse

This happens only in CSGO. When I am playing and I try to flick right or left quickly it often makes me stop moving my pov left or right and slings me the other direction and or down. I do not know what is going on or how to fix it.

I have tried a different mouse but it does the same thing.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Bad mousepad, mouse acceleration off, proper driver?

Comment: Does your mouse pad have a strange pattern?  I have a Steelseries mouse pad that has a weird hexagon pattern embossed on it that sends the mouse in random directions if I go too quick using some mice.

Comment: Are you playing on full screen? Or full screen windowed?